# Java Connection Refused on port 80

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm making proxy server and I've to receive request from browser and forward it to port 80 for HTTP request and get response from there. My receiving part is working fine but connection is refused on opening socket on port 80

`socket = new Socket("localhost",80);`

Help me how to solve this.

Comment: Can you give the exception text please

Answer (score 1):

Check few things

- Host name (localhost?) and port(80?) you're trying to connect to?
- The server side has managed to start listening correctly i.e. you have started server side process/java class?
- There's no firewall blocking the connection
- Port being already used by some other process?

Comment: Server side? I think my program will be client when I'm sending HTTP request header to port 80, right? Since I'm creating `Socket` and not the `SeverSocket`.

There is no firewall blocking.

Comment: Yes - if there is no one ready to reply/listen at port 80 then what will happen? Its basic client-server concept. What is the error - share your code and error otherwise we cant help you.